# FullCalendar rendering wrong Start date

Tags: javascript, datetime, fullcalendar

I have set my calendar timezone to default and also utc, but all my events are rendered 1 day before they should. 17 becomes 16 on screen etc.

For example, see an event the start date :

```
_ambigTime: true
_ambigZone: true
_d: Date 2018-07-16T00:00:00.000Z
_fullCalendar: true
_i: "/Date(1531774800000)/"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
_locale: Object { _week: {…}, _fullCalendar_weekCalc: "local" }
_offset: 0
_pf: Object { empty: false, overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, … }
```

as you can see for unknown reason the date 1531774800000 (17 July 2018, [convert here](https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html)) is converted to `Date 2018-07-16T00:00:00.000Z` by fullcalendar.

I have a feeling calendar uses some 'local' settings (as indicated in week calculation line `_fullCalendar_weekCalc: "local"`) conflicting with its own setting timezone not set to 'local'.

The only remedy to this is setting the timezone to 'local' what i'd like to avoid.
Any thoughts on how to stay utc and get correct display?..

EDIT: [image]

Comment: When I enter `1531774800000` into the calculator you linked to, it returns me `16/07/2018, 22:00:00` My local timezone is currently GMT summertime (so GMT+1). BTW the `Z` on the end of the string in fullCalendar is indicative of UTC time I believe. So yeah it's a timezone issue. Why do you want to avoid setting a timezone? Is `local` really the only / correct option? I think you'll need to clarify your requirements.

Comment: added an image to show its showing me 17thJuly.. id like to avoid local as i want time be client independent. Interesting it's showing you 16, im not getting it, i thought this converter was zone and locale independent..